# Windows10 docker: Grafana not able to access influxdb-502 Bad Gateway

Tags: windows, docker

I have installed two containers(influxdb and grafana) inside docker.
Two containers up and running. Able to access grafana(http://localhost:3000/datasources/edit/1/) and influxdb(http://localhost:8086/query?q=show%20databases) urls from browser.
But when we configure influxdb in grafana, grafana api throwing 502: Bad Gateway.

**Grafana log message**
t=2020-12-23T23:53:36+0000 lvl=eror msg="Data proxy error" logger=data-proxy-log userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/query remote_addr=xxx.xx.x.x referer=http://localhost:3000/datasources/edit/1/ error="http: proxy error: dial tcp localhost:8086: connect: connection refused"

t=2020-12-23T23:53:36+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/query status=502 remote_addr=1xxx.xx.x.x time_ms=26 size=0 referer=http://localhost:3000/datasources/edit/1/

**Docker Compose file:**
version: “2”
services:
grafana:
image: grafana/grafana
container_name: grafana
restart: always
ports:

- 3000:3000
  volumes:
- grafana_storage:/var/lib/grafana_storage
  networks:
- ranga_docker_network

influxdb:
image: influxdb
container_name: influxdb
restart: always
ports:

- 8086:8086
  volumes:
- influxdb_storage:/var/lib/influxdb_storage
  networks:
- ranga_docker_network
  environment:
- INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf
- INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf
- INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
- INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
- INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=telegraf1234
  networks:
  ranga_docker_network:
  volumes:
  grafana_storage:
  influxdb_storage:

Docker network also up and running.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker network ls

NETWORK ID NAME DRIVER SCOPE
f42bea59b834 bridge bridge local

5ae575311d19 host host local

d7f57802a04c monitoring_default bridge local

2419751561dd monitoring_monitoring bridge local

4829f3a73843 monitoring_ranga_docker_network bridge local

4962bd901e12 none null local

**ad245f671c22 ranga_docker_network bridge local**

Thanks,
Ranga Rao

Comment: If you take a moment to properly format your question (e.g., the docker-compose file should be formatted as a code sample), you'll probably find that people are more willing to spend time reading through it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Root cause: Connect VPN but didn't restart Docker daemon.
Resolution: Restart Docker daemon after connecting VPN.